# Asp.net application behavior after clearing Cache and History Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, browser, session-state

I have a web application built in asp.net 4.0. For user login management I have not used Cookie or Caching.Also, I have implemented a function which redirects to the Login page if session expires.

Question:
I have logged into the application and now I am clearing cache,cookies and browser data of the browser(google chrome). After clearing browser data I am refreshing the page of my application but it does not clear session nor redirects me to the Login Page.I was wondering if this behavior is OK or not.

**Update**:
Application is having cross browser compatibility.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It should be redirect to login page.Which browser you are using?

Comment: check the time of clear browsing data by default it is the past hour change it to more and check the required checkbox during clear browse data.

Comment: @SandipPatel as mentioned in question, it is google chrome.However, application is having cross browser compatibility.

Comment: It redirect to login in chrome and firefox. for IE you have to forcefully clear cookies from development tool (F12) --> Network --> Clear Cookie from domain

Comment: where are you calling the redirect function ? 
share some code for better preview

Comment: @WaqarAhmed My only concern is if I am clearing browser cache how should my system behave? Clearing and deleting the cache of browser should expire the session or not?

Comment: it should expire. but it is not as per your question.